# How to interpret $exp(L)$ in a scientific paper about logistic regression?

Tags: regression

I am reading a [paper by Bolton and Chapman](http://ruthnbolton.com/Publications/Track.pdf) about predicting horse races and I am having trouble understanding a certain formula. To give you the context, the paragraph is called: "Estimating the Parameters of the Multinomial Logit Model". It says:

> The likelihood function associated with a particular sample of races can be written in the following form for the multinomial logit model:
>   $$exp(L) = \prod_{j=1}^J P_{jh*}$$
>   where the *j* subscript denotes a race  *(j = 1, 2, ..., J), h** in equation (10) is the horse that is observed to win eace *j*, and *L* refers to the log-likelihood function.

*L* is said to be the log-likelihood but it is not clear how it fits in here. My question is then: how should one interpret this *exp(L)*, given that *L* is used as an argument to *exp* but is never used on the right side of the equation?

Note that it is not introduced previously in the text either.

Is it perhaps some shorthand notation or a convention one needs to be familiar with?

Comment: I notice the paper is from the 80's. I don't know if this is a problem in the field this paper is from, but in my studies, I notice a plague of poorly formulated notation that began in about 1982 and slowly died off starting around 1991.

Comment: At a glance, I can't see the meaning either, and it is likely using notation from a cited paper in the text, as a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they are just assuming you know that if you have a parametric model (either a parametric PMF or a parametric PDF) $p(x \mid \theta)$, and $n$ independent samples $\{ x_i \}_{i=1}^n$ from the distribution being modeled, then the likelihood for this sample is defined as $\ell(\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i \mid \theta)$. This product can be awkward to handle, so we often consider the log-likelihood $L(\theta):=\log(\ell(\theta))=\sum_{i=1}^n \log(p(x_i \mid \theta))$ instead.

Why they decided to refer to the exponential of the log-likelihood instead of just the likelihood itself, I couldn't tell you.

Comment: Yes! This is what I have been missing. After your answer I also read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function#Definition and the picture becomes clear.

So as far as I understand, the _L_ is what matters and they add the _exp_ around it to simplify the right side.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. $\exp(L)$ is another way to rewrite $e^L$